How to ensure for loop runs for more than 4000 rows in VBA?
How to increase VBA Do While loop efficiency?
I have the following code that needs to evaluate approximately 10000+ rows, but it only works for first 4000 rows post which the code return #VALUE! error
Function getManagerRating(EmpID As String)
    
    ' Adjust If you've got more rows
    ' or determine the number of filled rows
    Const NO_ROWS = 11841
    
    ' reading all cells into an arry
    ' it will be a 2D array
    Dim vdat As Variant
    vdat = Sheets("Master").Range("AA1:AA" & NO_ROWS)
            
    ' Declare all variable. That is good practise
    Dim i As Long, cellValue As Variant, ID As String, Position As Long, reqValue As String
    
    'Instead of a do loop one can use a for loop
    'using the lower and upper bound of the array
    For i = LBound(vdat) To UBound(vdat)
        'cellValue = Sheets("Master").Range("AA" & row_number)
        cellValue = vdat(i, 1)
        ID = Left$(cellValue, 8)
        If ID = EmpID Then
            If InStr(cellValue, "Overall Rating By Manager") > 0 Then
                Position = Len(cellValue) - InStr(cellValue, "@")
                reqValue = Right$(cellValue, Position)
                ' It seems that EmpID is unique
                ' i.e. you can leave the loop here
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i
              
    getManagerRating = reqValue
End Function


The code will run till row 11841 (any reason you hardcode this value?), unless you get a runtime error. So the question is at which statement do you get the error and what causes the eror? Both question can be answered only by yourself. A possible reason could be that vdat(i, 1) contains a value where the Left-function fails (eg an error value).

Is there a special reason to use a Variant object instead of a Range Object to loop over?

Agree with @FunThomas. Try calling your function from code and see what the error is.

@Jan_B: Sure: The data is read into memory (into a 2-dimensional array) at once and therefore the code much faster.

@FunThomas Nice, this was news to me! Does this retain all the Range or Cell properties/objects in the first dimension?

After cellValue = vdat(i, 1) add line If IsError(cellValue) Then getManagerRating = "Error on Master cell AA " & i: Exit Function

@Jan_B: No, it copies only the values. In fact, it's a shorter version of writing vdat = Sheets("Master").Range("AA1:AA" & NO_ROWS).Value.

Using Application.Match directly on the worksheet is faster than looping:
Function getManagerRatingMatch(EmpID As String)
    Dim cellValue As Variant, m, rng As Range, pos As Long
    
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range("AA1:AA11841")
    m = Application.Match(EmpID & "*", rng, 0)
    
    If Not IsError(m) Then               'got a match?
        cellValue = rng.Cells(m).Value
        If InStr(cellValue, "Overall Rating By Manager") > 0 Then
            pos = Len(cellValue) - InStr(cellValue, "@")
            getManagerRatingMatch = Right$(cellValue, pos)
        End If
    End If
End Function

